# optional arguments function

Tags: python

I am searching how I could use optional arguments in python.
I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585247/python-optional-parameters) but it is not clear to me.
Lets say I have a function f that can take 1 or more arguments to understand time series. Am i obliged to specify the number of arguments and set default values for each argument?
What I aim to do is being able to write a function this way:

simple function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return x + y
#f(1,2) returns 3
```

**What i want is also f(1,2,3) to return me 6 and f(7) returning me 7**

**Is it possible to write it without setting a predefined number of mandatory/optional parameters?
Is it possible to write it without having to set default values to 0 ?
How to write this function?**

Its a simple example with numbers but the function i need to write is comparing a set of successive objects. After comparison is done, the data set will feed a neural network.

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**:
Objects I am feeding my function with are tuples like this (float,float,float,bool,string)

Comment: Would passing a list as an argument work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put [`*args`](http://basicpython.com/understanding-arguments-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) in your function and then take arbitrary (non-keyword) arguments. *args is a tuple, so you can iterate over it like any Python tuple/list/iterable. IE:

```
def f(*args):
    theSum = 0
    for arg in args:
        theSum += arg
    return theSum

print f(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: that is seksy programming paradigm

Answer (score 4):

```
def f(*args):
    """
        >>> f(1, 2)
        3

        >>> f(7)
        7

        >>> f(1, 2, 3)
        6

        >>> f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        21
    """
    return sum(args)
```

If you need to do something more complicated than sum you could just iterate over `args` like this:

```
def f(*args):
    r = 0
    for arg in args:
        r += arg
    return r
```

See this question for [more information on *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean)

Also see this sections on the Python tutorial: [Arbitray Argument List](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Comment: You should show OP how to do the summation in a loop to make it slightly more explicit that `args` is a tuple in the function.  (But don't delete the answer with `sum`.  Ultimately, that's more idiomatic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow syntax:

```
def f(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

The `*` before `args` tells it to "swallow up" all arguments, makng `args` a tuple.  You can also mix this form with standard arguments, as long as the `*args` goes last.  For example:

```
def g(a,b,*args):
    return a * b * sum(args)
```

The first example uses the built-in `sum` function to total up the arguments.  `sum` takes a sequence as adds it up for you:

```
>>> sum([1,3,5])
9
>>> sum(range(100))
4950
```

The `args` name is not mandatory but is used by convention so best to stick with it.  There is also `**kwargs` for undefined keyword arguments.