# Append changing all elements from list, python

Tags: python, json, list, class, append

I am working on something which should manage multiple water dispensers. I need to get some data from a json file and then load it into objects after that, append the objects to a list. For some reason list.append changes other object's parameters(more specific, location). Here is my code:

WaterDispenser.py

```
class WaterDispenser():
    def __init__(self, id: int = -1, status: bool = False, location: list=[-1, -1]) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.status = status
        self.location = location
    
    def Dump(self) -> dict:
        """Dumps the propoerties in a json dictionary
        
        Returns
        -------
        dict
            A dictionary with a collection of propoerties and their names
        """
        
        return {"id": self.id, "status": self.status, "location":[self.location[0], self.location[1]]}

    def Load(self, object: dict) -> None:
        """Loads the json dictoinary in memory

        Parameters
        ----------
        object : dict, required
            The json file with the properties of the dispenser

        Returns
        -------
        None
        """
        
        self.id = object["id"]
        self.status = object["status"]
        self.location[0] = object["location"][0]
        self.location[1] = object["location"][1]
        return None
```

main.py

```
import json
from WaterDispenser import WaterDispenser

dispensers = []

def LoadDispensers(path: str = "dispensers.json") -> int:
    """Loads the json file in memory.

    Parameters
    ---------
    path : str, optional
        The path of the file to be loaded. Defaults to "dispensers.json".

    Returns
    -------
    int
        Count of dispensers data loaded
    """
    
    global dispensers
    
    dispensers = []
    
    data = json.load(open(path, "r"))

    for d in data:
        x = WaterDispenser()
        x.Load(d)
        dispensers.append(x)
        
    return len(dispensers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(LoadDispensers())
    
    print([o.Dump() for o in dispensers])
```

dispensers.json

```
[
    {"id": 0, "status": true, "location": [0, 0]},
    {"id": 1, "status": true, "location": [0, 1]},
    {"id": 2, "status": false, "location": [1, 1]}
]
```

Output:

```
3
[{'id': 0, 'status': True, 'location': [1, 1]}, {'id': 1, 'status': True, 'location': [1, 1]}, {'id': 2, 'status': False, 'location': [1, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional answer:

Change the init of `WaterDispenser` to

```py
from typing import Optional

class WaterDispenser():
    def __init__(self, id: int = -1, status: bool = False, location: Optional[list] = None) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.status = status
        self.location = location or [-1, -1]
```

This should result in the expected response of

```
3
[{'id': 0, 'status': True, 'location': [0, 0]}, {'id': 1, 'status': True, 'location': [0, 1]}, {'id': 2, 'status': False, 'location': [1, 1]}]
```

The ***why***:

Generally you want to avoid using mutable values as kwarg values because they're pre-computed (so your default `location` argument was technically the same object in memory across your `WaterDispenser` instances). `append` wasn't the culprit here and you can read more about this all via [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) or read a succinct explanation via [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18151442).

Design note:

It's worth noting that the way you are using `Load` in the above example could just be folded into `WaterDispenser.__init__`, so something like

```py
from typing import Dict, Any

class WaterDispenser():
    def __init__(self, data: Dict[Any]) -> None:
        self.id = data.get("id", -1)
        self.status = data.get("status", False)
        self.location = data.get("location", [-1, -1])
```

or if you want to avoid `typing`

```py
class WaterDispenser():
    def __init__(self, data: dict) -> None:
        self.id = data.get("id", -1)
        self.status = data.get("status", False)
        self.location = data.get("location", [-1, -1])
```

That example still includes your default values but if you removed the secondary arguments from those `get` calls you could protect against missing data at runtime without having to check to see if you had, say, an impossible location data point like [-1, -1].